# Airport transit visa from Brussels (Belgium) to Geneva

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a US green card holder. I am traveling from Ouagadougou (Burkina Faso) to New York. The airline is Brussels airline and from Brussel we need to tranfer to another plane that will take us from Brussels to Geneva, there we can go to New York. I would like to know if I need a Schengen airport transit visa for the Brussels-Geneva leg.

Comment: yes, you need a schengen visa as you will enter the schengen area

Answer (score 2):

Brussels and Geneva are both in the Schengen area. For this reason, the flight to Geneva will depart from another part of the airport than the flight from Ouagadougou and there will generally be no passport check on arrival in Geneva.

Because of that, **an airport transit visa is not enough** and the US green card does not help either. You will enter the Schengen area in Brussels and leave it in Geneva, with a passport check and stamp in each case and for that you need a regular Schengen visa (if you are a citizen of Burkina Faso).

See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Relaxed, I'm sure you agree that, although you probably won't be checked going from Brussels to Geneva (because of Schengen), they certainly can check you if they want and they often do. Just the other day I happened to be checked simply going from france to suisse, fortunately I had my passport with me.

Comment: @JoeBlow That's possible but my point is that because of this lack of *systematic* check, it's not possible to separate passengers in transit from other passengers *in Geneva*, which is why you need to enter the Schengen area *in Brussels*. The OP's passport will be checked both in Brussels and in Geneva, but not specifically in relation to the internal Schengen flight. Another thing that could happen is a police check right at the gate of the incoming flight from Ouagadougou.

Comment: For sure, 100%.  I was commenting **purely** on this phrase: "there will be no passport check on arrival in Geneva"  That phrase is wrong, on the face of it.  I know what you meant ("the schengen passport check must and does happen in brussels, not in geneva") but regarding in geneve, "you usually won't be checked any more coming from brussels to geneve, although occasinoally they will do so"

Comment: @JoeBlow I edited the answer, I could also write “There will almost certainly be no passport check”. But I don't think these small nuances make the sentence “wrong”. Incidentally, checks around the border or on trains are more akin to random police checks that can happen anywhere in many countries rather than to regular border checks that would be more-or-less systematic in other parts of the world. Also, were you specifically asked for your passport on crossing the land border? A customs check would seem more common but the OP wouldn't face that when transiting at the airport.

Comment: Most importantly, I don't know that they “often” do. I happen to have taken such flights many times and never encountered a police check.

Comment: (I beg your pardon, to confuse matters, I gave the example of the UK - which is of course out of the schengen area!)